# Firefox OS: Hot to test your hosted app with firefox OS desktop client and marionett

Tags: firefox-os

I want to run UI tests on my firefox os application. I would like to use marionett for this, so I downloaded the B2G desktop client. It works fine, but I can not figure out, how could I add my hosted app to the desktop client to be able to test it with marionett.

Could you help me?
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Using the Gaia marionette runner to test your application or?

Comment: Yes exactly. Or is there a better way to UI test your Firefox OS app?

Comment: Check out this presentation, it has some links. Haven't figured it out myself yet. http://bebef1987.github.io/slides/AppDays/AppDays.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a packaged app to Firefox OS destop (desktop B2G)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564378/how-to-add-a-packaged-app-to-firefox-os-destop-desktop-b2g)