# How to add a packaged app to Firefox OS destop (desktop B2G)

Tags: firefox-os

I'm developing an application for Firefox OS, and need to run Marionette tests (it is needed for my university thesis).

As I know there are two ways of doing this:

- you have a Marionette enabled device
- with B2G desktop

I don't have such a device so I tried the B2G desktop. Marionette is working fine, but I couldn’t find any resources that would explain me, how to add my own application to B2G desktop (it would be a packaged app).

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Have you developed packaged app? and You want to test it on real device or B2G?

Comment: Finally I successfully put a marionette-enabled OS to FFOS. But in my original question I wanted to use B2G with packaged app. But I could not put my packaged app into B2G (There is an apps folder in Gaia, but I figured out, that it is not enough simply to copy my app into that folder).

Comment: In Firefox app manager choose packaged app, then route to Gaia folder Apps. Select which app you wanted to open. Their are basic apps needed for Firefox OS mobile to function. The each folder has separate **manifest.webapp** file. Just point to require folder(No need to copy) and open the app. Make sure u have pulled the latest gaia from gitHub.

Comment: I would like to achive the opposite effect :). You describe how to run a b2g-s native app in the firefox OS simulator. But what I would like is to run my own packaged app in desktop B2G. (the simulator is not good for me, because it does not contain marionette server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not an official documentation about how to push an app to Firefox OS Desktop. But you can do it manually at the moment you compile Gaia. Follow the steps from [Building the B2G desktop client](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Building_the_B2G_desktop_client) and at [Downloading Gaia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Building_the_B2G_desktop_client#Downloading_Gaia) step you need to do:

Download Gaia for the first time, clone the source code repository on GitHub:

```
git clone https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia
cd gaia
```

Or update an already existing clone of Gaia, you can pull in the latest changes from GitHub:

```
cd gaia
git pull
```

Now into the directory *"apps/"* create a new folder with the name of your app and inside of it put the content of your app. You will get a structure like this:

```
gaia/
- apps/
  - homescreen/
  - ...
  - ...
  - my-custom-app/
    - manifest.webapp
    - index.html
    - js/
    - ...
  - keyboard/
  - ...
- bin/
- build/
- ...
```

Of course, the folder for you custom app in this example is **my-custom-app** but you can use whatever name that you like.

Now follow the rest of the steps on the [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Building_the_B2G_desktop_client#Creating_a_custom-settings.json) and you will have your app pulled to the Firefox OS desktop ready to work.

I am not sure about this step, but I am remember that every time you change something on your app or you add a new app to the *gaia/apps/* folder, you need to [create the profile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Building_the_B2G_desktop_client#Generating_a_profile) again every time you make a change and you like to see it live on the Desktop B2G. So, with this I am sure you can test and let me now if I am right.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I think right now it is possible to add a custom B2G or Gaia to a Simulator, so the apps can be uploaded via WebIDE. However on my Ubuntu machine it does not work (It has some connection error), so I use the solution you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you want to deploy (install) your app from the desktop to the same desktop. Unfortunately it is not currently possible to just select your app and install it on desktop the same way you'd do it on a device or simulator. This issue is raised here :

https://ffdevtools.uservoice.com/forums/246087-firefox-developer-tools-ideas/suggestions/6344638-manage-firefox-on-desktop-the-same-way-as-firefoxo

I encourage anyone to vote for it if it'd be useful to you too.

However if you set up your own custom local server or host it on the web, then you can install your app on your desktop from it (basically your server would emulate a local "marketplace" or a local web site providing a web app).

UPDATE : Now the webIDE as a "Local Runtime" which might allow in the future to install, run and debug apps on Firefox for desktop the same way as on devices or simulators.